# What regex matches strings of consecutive 'a' and 'b'?

Tags: regex

I need a regex which matches strings of consecutive `a` and `b`, e.g.:

```
ababa
bab
```

Edge case (smallest):

```
ab
ba
```

(No upper limit.)

...and **shouldn't** match:

```
abba
bbab
bbaabb
```

I've tried several regex but this one is kind of tricky. Can you throw me any hints?

My tries:

- `(a|b)+`
- `(ab|ba)*(aba|bab)+`

This one gets really close! http://www.regexr.com/38lqg

Comment: Well, show us what you've tried.

Comment: when defining a problem, the edge cases are really important. what's the smallest acceptable match? `ab` and `ba`?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath correct

Comment: `^(ab)+a?$|^(ba)+b?$`

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov: I guess you meant `+`.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov, that wouldn't work for 'aba'

Comment: @sshashank124: it does. actually the problem is with `ab`

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov doesn't work: http://www.regexr.com/38lqj

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to find matches within a text (potentially several words per line):

```
\b(((ab)+a?)|((ba)+b?))\b
```

`\b` is for word boundary.

Comment: how can we make this generic like for every consecutive character ? is it possible just wandering.

Comment: @sjcipher: not sure I understand.. what kind of strings do you want to match?

Comment: I think @sjcipher means if there's a regex to match all strings with consecutive sequences, not only 'a' and 'b'. I believe that question should be its own question/thread.

Comment: if i put that as new question some guy will surely point as duplicate to this question :) never mind i will try.

Answer (score 1):

```
    string[] abTestsPass = {
        "ababa",
        "bab",
        "ab",
        "ba",
    };
    string[] abTestsFail = {
        "abba",
        "bbab",
        "bbaabb",
        "a",
        "b",
        "",
    };

    Regex regex = new Regex("^(ab|a?(ba)+b?)$");

    foreach (string test in abTestsFail)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(!regex.IsMatch(test));
    foreach (string test in abTestsPass)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(regex.IsMatch(test));
```

<s>The down-side to this is that it will also match `"a"`, `"b"` and `""`. Is that acceptable?</s>

Changed the regex. Added more test cases.

Comment: Minimal cases: "ab", "ba" (see question). So, it doesn't. Thanks!

Comment: This pattern match with "a", "b" and "".

Comment: I've updated the Regex to take account of that, and added the test cases to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use something like this:

```
^(?:ab(?:ab)*a?|ba(?:ba)*b?)$
```

---

EDIT: Definitely can be shortened to:

```
^(?:(?:ab)+a?|(?:ba)+b?)$
```

---

EDIT:

Strictly shortest if there are always `a` and `b` in the string:

```
\b((.)(?!\2))+.\b
```

But if there can be something else:

```
\b(([ab])(?!\2))+[ab]\b
```

Comment: @KennyMeyer I don't think regexr is the right tool. I can't seem to use the multiline mode for checking multiple individual strings. Try [this](http://regex101.com/r/sU0qC4).

Comment: @Jerry: it's the right tool if you want to find matches within a text.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Okay, finally found the multiline mode: http://www.regexr.com/38lr2 If you are checking against multiple sequences in a sentence, use `\b` instead of `^` and `$`.

Comment: Yes, with `\b` this works! Thanks, @Karoly got it right first, technically, so I accepted his answer

Comment: @KennyMeyer It's okay. I was just sticking to the examples in your question (one word per line).

Answer (score -1):

```
(ab)(?!(ab|bb))
```

just like that, i tested and is less complex than other answers
can you try again.